# One of two functions not writing file

Tags: python, dataframe

I've been working on this script and I've recently been trying to get it cleaner by putting everything in its own function. The code below runs without errors, gets the data I want and saves it to MongoDB, but it doesn't write the csv.

The functions `save_db` and `save_csv` are very similar, I don't understand why `save_db` works and `save_csv` doesn't. Also I want to use the `ldf` variable in both functions; do I have to set `ldf = make_df(data)` in both or is there a way to share `ldf` to `save_csv` since it's being called in `save_db` already?

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient
import os, time

market_symbols = []
candleInterval = '1'

def get_candle(marketSymbol):      
    candle_url = f'https://api.kraken.com/0/public/OHLC?pair={marketSymbol}&interval={candleInterval}'
    candle_data = requests.get(candle_url)
    bytes_value = candle_data.content
    my_json = bytes_value.decode('utf8').replace("'", '"')
    data = (json.loads(my_json))
    data['symbol'] = marketSymbol    
    return data

def make_df(data):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data['result'])        
    unnested_df = pd.concat([
        pd.DataFrame(df[x].tolist()).add_prefix(f'{x}_') 
        for x in df
    ], axis=1)   
    
    fdf = unnested_df
    fdf.columns =['Timestamp', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Vwap', 'Volume', 'Count', 'Last']   
    fdf.drop('Last',axis=1,inplace=True) 
    fdf.insert(1, 'Time', pd.to_datetime(fdf.Timestamp, unit='s'))  
    fdf.insert(9, 'Pair', data['symbol'])
    ldf=fdf.iloc[[-2]]
    print(ldf)  
    return ldf

def save_db(data): 
    ldf = make_df(data)
    db_name = 'KTDB'
    db_collect = 'intermittent'
    client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
    kdb = client[db_name]          
    pdata = ldf.to_dict(orient='records')  
    kdb[db_collect].insert_many(pdata)    

def save_csv(data):        
    ldf = make_df(data)
    csv_file = f"ktester-{candleInterval}.csv"    

    if(csv_file in os.listdir()): #append, file exists 
        csv_string = ldf.to_csv(index=False, encoding='utf-8', header=False)
        with open(csv_file, 'a') as f:
            f.write(csv_string)
    else: #write new file
        csv_string = ldf.to_csv(index=False, encoding='utf-8')
        with open(csv_file, 'w') as f:
            f.write(csv_string)  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    candle_symbols = ['XBTUSD', 'ADAUSD']
    
    
    for symbol in candle_symbols:
        tick_data = get_candle(symbol) 
        save_db(tick_data)                            
        save_csv(tick_data)
```

Comment: Did you do any debugging? Like, stepping through the code in a GUI debugger?

Comment: No, but now I think I have a different problem entirely. I have this script running through cron. and thats the issue, I think its the OS part since cron runs from root and this is looking for local. Im not sure. but I just ran this code outside of cron and it worked just fine.

Comment: Your ```ldf``` is a dataframe, am I wrong? If so, you can literally export it with ```ldf.to_csv(csv_file, index=False, encoding='utf-8')```. There is no need to use a file descriptor.

Comment: I do that, its in the if statements of the save_csv function

Comment: Can you try with an absolute path for the CSV file? this might help you figure out the issue

Comment: Its writing the file to root since cron runs it from root. So I guess nevermind y'all, I got it. Now if you can suggest how to control where its saved that would be helpful

Comment: Take a closer look, you are not using the ```to_csv``` function correctly, it does not return a string, but immediately writes to a file, and you didn't specify the file name for it. Maybe that way it will work

Comment: if I add an absolute path to the csv file it never appends for some reason. Theres probably a better way of doing this.

Comment: csv_file is the second line in that function it assigns the name

Comment: @Moti: But if no file name is provided, doesn't `to_csv` return a string?

Comment: @robothead did it fail to append even when passing the full path to `os.listdir()` in the `if(csv_file in os.listdir()):` line? Also, the fact that you didn't debug this beforehand isn't ideal; StackOverflow generally requires a lot more research effort on the part of askers, and debugging is one of the most basic, day one things a programmer should learn, and certainly should do before asking for help. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/6273251

Comment: thanks for the reprimand Random, very helpful